# Content and before-element on opposite sides of div-box

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a couple of divs with a few characters/words as content and a word as before-element. I want the before-content on the left side of the div-box and the content on the right side:

BEFORE__________________________________________CONTENT
BEFORE____________________________________OTHER CONTENT
BEFORE_____________________________________MORE CONTENT

Margin-right between the before-element and the content doesn't work here because if the content becomes longer or shorter, the before-element will move, too. Does anyone know how to set it so that the before-element and the content stick to the sides of the div? I don't want to use a flexbox with two divs because I want to define "BEFORE" via CSS.

Here's the basic code:

```
.box {
    width: 500px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--col2);
    text-align: right;
 }
 .box:before {
    content: "BEFORE";
    text-align: left;
 }
```

I tried with flexbox already, but without success. The before-element is stuck to the content.

Comment: do you mean something like this https://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/gOLxqjB?

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for! Thank you very much! (Can I mark your comment as the solution? - I'm new to that.)

Comment: You welcome, I'll post it as an anwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give the `before` a `position:absolute` with `left:0`, also `.box` should have a `position:relative`

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:60%;
  height:200px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: silver;
}
.box {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px
}
.box:before {
  content: "BEFORE";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    Item One
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Item Two
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Item Three
  </div>
</div>
```